# MySqli query has effected rows but wont show result

Tags: php, mysql

I have worked with basic SQL for some time now and any problems that I run into are simple. I don't know if I am missing something but I have made a normal connection to my mySQL server that has a result (`num_rows = 1`) but nothing will show via `mysqli_fetch_array` or `fetch_assoc`.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM support WHERE steamid = '".$steamprofile['***']."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row["email"];
}
```

Comment: your query is dependant on `$steamprofile['***']`. Plus, you need to "echo" that row. You're not doing anything with `$row["email"];`.

Comment: I have used this exact same way of using variables in a query through out my hole website at it works on all other pages. And I am trying to echo information from the same row that the $steamprofile['***'] is in

Comment: `$row["email"];` does nothing; it's a stray.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I copied the code I missed out the "echo". But it still doesn't work.

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to your query. I don't know what else to tell you beyond that.

Comment: please see what error in coming from mysql

Comment: No error. I used var_dump and the num_rows = 1 as it should.

Comment: make sure there are no spaces playing tricks on you. Your question is next to unanswerable for what you posted.

Comment: `result (num_rows = 1)` is that supposed to be part of your "actual" running code? and again, no way of knowing where `$steamprofile` is coming from and your title is deceiving. I have to pass on this question. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I understand, very sorry, I don't normally post on here. Maybe something to do with my host, I will drop them a ticket.

Comment: `MySqli query has effected rows ` SELECT queries don't have effected rows, so you're looking at something else. Look for row count

Comment: Yes, row count. Wrong word sorry.

Comment: I would separate this line like this `$query = "SELECT * FROM support WHERE steamid = '.$steamprofile['***'].' " ;` then you just add  `$query` and so it would look like this `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)`  not sure if it works but check it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may alter you code like this.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM support WHERE steamid = '".$steamprofile['***']."'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$row["email"];
}
```

I think `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` was the bug.

Comment: You *think* it was a bug? You're not sure?